# Find a square matrix whose characteristic polynomial is $P(z)$

Tags: complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given the following polynomial $P(z)=z^4+z^3-5z^2+z-6$, how do I find a square matrix $(A)$, of dimension 4, both with real coefficients and complex coefficients whose characteristic polynomial is $P(z)$? I have found that the roots are $z_1 = 2$, $z_2 = −3$, $z_3 = i$, $z_4 = −i$, but I do not understand how to go on. Could you help me please?

Comment: Hint: consider placing the roots on the diagonal. Obviously for the real case you'll have to make an adjustment

Comment: @bounceback From the wording of the question, it sounds like one matrix should suffice. Unless it was meant "both a matrix with only real coefficients and a matrix with complex coefficients," which would be a strange way of interpreting what was asked.